# In Sympy, what is equivalent to Mathematica's symbolic minimize function?

Tags: python, sympy, minimization

Mathematica has a symbolic solver for quadratic (and maybe other) functions, e.g.:

```
Minimize[2 x^2 - y x + 5, {x}]
```

will yield the following solution:

```
{1/8 (40-y^2),{x->y/4}}
```

Is this feature supported in SymPy or a derivative library? Or I have to implement it myself?

Thanks a lot for your opinion!

Comment: There isn't one; one has to write some code using `diff`, `solve` (or `solveset`), and worry about endpoints / behavior at infinity, or use second derivative test, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the generality of this approach, but the following code:

```
import sympy
from sympy.solvers import solve

x = sympy.var('x')
y = sympy.var('y')

f = 2*x**2 - y*x + 5

r = solve(f.diff(x), x)
f = f.subs(x, r[0])

print(f)    
print(r)
```

Outputs:

```
-y**2/8 + 5
[y/4]
```

The first line of output (`-y**2/8 + 5`) is equivalent to Mathematica's `1/8 (40-y^2)`, just ordered differently.

The second line (`[y/4]`) is similar to Mathematica's `{x->y/4}` (`solve` returns a list of roots)

The idea is that we first take the partial derivative of `f` with respect to `x`, then substitute it into the original function.

Comment: The generality of this approach is limited, for example if the function was `-(2*x**2 - y*x + 5)`, then it would give the same `y/4` even though it's now the maximum instead of minimum. There may be multiple zeros of the derivative, and one has to compare the values of f at each of them to the limits of f as x->infinity or negative infinity (the latter can be found with SymPy, too).